# Uploading files using Ajax, Json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, upload, blob

I want to upload a file using ajax and json.  The PHP file has a form with multipart.  I want to pass a file oo my js file and use ajax and json to pass file to my upload file.  The only part of the code that I have an issue with is the album_cover which is a file.  The following works for all inputted text, but don't know how to upload a file.

The id for the file is called album_cover.

```
<form action="" method="post" name="artist_create_song_album" id="artist_create_song_album" class="smart-form client-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="album_cover" id="album_cover" placeholder="Album Cover">
```

The following JS file is called.

```
runAllForms();
$(function () {
    $("#artist_create_song_album").validate({
        rules: {
            album_cover: {
                required: true
            },
            song_album_name: {
                required: true
            },
            song_album_description: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        // messages for form validation
        messages: {
            album_cover: {
                required: 'Please upload album cover'
            },
            song_album_name: {
                required: 'Please enter album name'
            },
            song_album_description: {
                required: 'Please enter album description'
            }
        },

        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        },
        submitHandler: function () {
            $('#artist_create_song_album').hide(0);
            $('#art_song_message').hide(0);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'artist_update_songs.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    album_cover: $('#album_cover').val(),
                    song_album_name: $('#song_album_name').val(),
                    song_album_description: $('#song_album_description').val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#art_song_message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                    .text(data.msg).show(500);
                    if (data.error === true) {
                        if (data.goto == 1) {
                            window.location = "http://dev.worldmusicstage.com/main.php#/ajax/artist_dashboard_info.php";
                            $('#artist_create_song_album').show(500);
                            delete json;
                        } else {

                            $('#artist_create_song_album').show(500);
                        }
                    }
                    if (data.error === false) {
                        window.location = "http://dev.worldmusicstage.com/main.php#/ajax/artist_dashboard_info.php";
                        $('#artist_create_song_album').show(500);
                        delete json;
                    }
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#art_song_message').removeClass().addClass('error')
                    alert('The error was: ' + errorThrown);
                    alert('The error was: ' + XMLHttpRequest);
                    alert('The error was: ' + textStatus);
                    alert(errorThrown.stack)
                    $('#artist_create_song_album').show(500);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: http://www.dropzonejs.com/ also good option to upload file without page postback.

Comment: I have dropzone on the site but for some reason I can only use two instances of dropzone.  If I add a third instance, it doesn't work.  Not quite sure what is happening there.

Answer (score -1):

You CAN NOT upload file via (truth) ajax. You can create iframe and targeted upload form (`<form target="framename">`) for this iframe.

Comment: I thought there was a way to send the file as a blob.  Can this not be done?

Comment: Modern browsers (js engine) can this. But not all and have different api. And for compatible you need use send form via iframe.